# Gradle sync failing without dependency being added in gradle file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am facing this weird error while compiling an app. I see this error in the message window:

[Error shown while syncing Android project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pufmR.png)

These are all the dependencies I have added in my app's build.gradle:

[dependency list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMHTr.png)

I don't understand that why these errors are popping up without me adding the dependencies in the gradle file why is it giving these errors and how to resolve them?

Comment: In the future, rather than posting screenshots of text files (such as your app's `build.gradle` file), post the text of the text files.

Comment: "I don't understand that why these errors are popping up without me adding the dependencies in the gradle file" -- Gradle supports transitive dependencies. The dependencies that you add, in turn, depend upon other dependencies, and so on. Gradle will attempt to pull in all of them. The Play Services dependencies, or possibly the Facebook SDK, apparently depend upon those older pieces of the Support Library.

Comment: "how to resolve them?" -- If you mean "how can I get the build to pull in those dependencies?", click the "Install repository and sync project" link for one of them, as the answers have indicated. That, in turn, will cause a conflict with your `23.4.0` support libraries. `23.4.0` is rather old, so you might switch them to `25.3.1` to match what the other libraries are seeking.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare your comment makes a lot of sense. I didn't know about Gradle's trasitive dependency feature. Please add this comment as answer and I will be happy to upvote your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle supports transitive dependencies. The dependencies that you add in turn, depends upon other dependencies, and so on. Gradle will attempt to pull in all of them. That might be the reason why you see these errors. Probably if you use support libraries, you use these repositories.

Comment: Thanks, it really helped!

Answer (score 1):

In future cases, add the files and errors into the question. Don't show screenshots.

---

You see the "install and sync project" button, right? The support repo is a part of the SDK, which means you need to install it to get the newest features. Which means you have to press the "install and sync project" button, as this means you don't have the SDK artifact installed.

They are appearing because you don't have the support repo installed, and you can fix it by pressing the "install and sync project" button.

I don't know what import adds the extra imports, but it I assume one of the dependencies you have imports them. THere are a lot of dependencies

Comment: Can you tell pros/cons of keeping unused imports?

Comment: I feel that the extra imports added will clutter the app and will make the app size larger which would be bad. I may be wrong here :)

Answer (score 0):

Click on "Install repository and sync project"

Comment: but don't you think installing repository and sync project again shouldn't be required because I am not even using those repositories which are missing! I am confused here...

Comment: @RahulDhangar If you use support libraries, you use this repositories

Comment: hmm... makes sense.